# C++ sqlite3 how to know that an sql statement execute successfully?

Tags: c++, sqlite

C++ sqlite3 how to know that an sql statement execute successfully?

I am trying to insert a record with sqlite3

I wanna know how to know if its successful

```
string sqlstatement = "INSERT INTO abe_account (name,department,password) VALUES ("
+quotesql(name) + ","
+quotesql(department) + ","
+quotesql(password) + ");";

   if (sqlite3_open("abeserver.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
    sqlite3_prepare( db, sqlstatement.c_str(), -1, &stmt, NULL );//preparing the statement
    sqlite3_step( stmt );//executing the statement
        }
    else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open db\n";
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

How do we get the success signal from sqlite3 like when a row is added successfully or a row is deleted succesfully etc and assign the value to a boolean or a string

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3_step()` has a number of return values in the form of an integer. Code 0 indicates a succesfull execution of a statement. You can find the rest of the codes [here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)

> How do we .. assign that value to a variable

```
if ( ! sqlite3_step( stmt ) ) cout << "it worked" << endl
```

Comment: Python? :) `if ( ! sqlite3_step( stmt ) ) cout << "it worked" << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
if(sqlite3_step(stmt)!=SQLITE_DONE)
{
  error handling here
}
```

And here's some documentation on sqlite3 constants:[Result Codes](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)